# How to look for a string in a dataframe name but not in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, contains

I would like to know how to use str.contains for a dataframe name but not in a column of the dataframe. I have a df1 with a column target that contains strings such as lung, tum, liver, etc. And I have multiples df2 which contains the specific target in their names. I would like to create a loop to do condition when the name of the df2 contains the specific target that is in df1. It would be something like :

```
if df2.str.contains(target in df1):
do condition
```

I can create a list that contains all targets with this :

```
target_available = df1['target'].unique().tolist()
```

So it would be :

```
if df2.str.contains(target_available):
do condition
```

So for my df2 called XXX_dataframe, when XXX is equal to the target that is in target_available, then do condition / when XXX is equal to another target that is in target_available, then do condition / etc.

Examples :

```
# Few columns of a df
# The column target can have other possibilities
Model_rad = {'model_uid': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
               
               'pathology': ['nsclc', 'nsclc', 'nsclc', 'covid', 'glioma', 'meningioma', 'gbm', 'breast-cancer'],
               'purpose': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
               
               'target': ['lung', 'tum', 'tum', 'lung', 'tum', 'tum', 'tum', 'tum'],
               
     
               'version_availability': ['v0.0', 'v1.0', '', 'v1.0', 'v1.0', 'v1.0', '', '']
               } 

# Creating the df
Model_rad= pd.DataFrame(Model_rad)

# Before creating target_ref_series data frames we need to get unique values from target in Model_rad
target_unique = Model_rad['target'].unique().tolist() 

# Creating data frames target ref series
for target in target_unique: # For each target in model rad
    # We create empty data frames target ref series from rad
    vars()[target+'_ref_series_from_rad'] = pd.DataFrame() 

# The data frames target_ref_series_from_rad have some columns but we don't need them for now

# for each models available in the column version availability
for models in Model_rad.version_availability:  
    #print(models)
    # If models exist (column where models not empty so different than '')
    if models != '':
        print(models)
        # We create the variable patho_and_target_available which is the pathology where models are not empty
        patho_and_target_available = Model_rad[Model_rad['version_availability'] != '']
```

So at this moment the idea is like:

```
when target in vars()[target+'_ref_series_from_rad'] is equals to target_available in patho_and_target_available['target'] : 

do condition
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there small input data (with correct formatting) and expected output?

Comment: It's done ! I hope it's better , thank you !

Comment: Looking at your code, you probably looking for `Model_rad.groupby(["target", "version_availability"])`  But without expected results its hard to tell exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure what you mean, but if you want to check if a column name equals some string you can use df.columns.values. This gives you a list of column names.

If you want to check if the contents of a column match a specific string you could use df['column'] == 'query' to obtain a true/false series.
Furthermore, you could use this as df_query = df[df['column'] == 'query'] to get a filtered dataframe.

Might you want to store a filtered dataframe for each of your look up values, then consider a dictionary:

```
df_dict = {}
for val in lookup_values:
   df_dict[val] = df[df['column'] == val]
```